# String searching in linked list by C

Tags: c, linked-list

Facing problem in while loop for if condition, 
conditional values are equal but not going inside in if condition.

```
void searchList(char name[20])
    {
        char contactName[20];
        strcpy(contactName,name);
        struct node *temp = head;
        printf("\nSearch Contact : \n");
        printf("-------------------\n");
        printf("Name : %s\n",name);
        while (temp != NULL)
        {
            if(temp->name == contactName)
            {
                printf("Contact Name : %s\n",temp->name);
                printf("Contact Number : %s\n", temp->phone);
            }
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use strcmp to compare strings, equating string names doesn't work in C. String name actually represents address of first location, so you are actually comparing addresses and not the strings.

Comment: Use `strcmp`  to compare strings in C. E.g `if(temp->name == contactName)` --> `if(strcmp(temp->name,  contactName) ==0)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the strcmp function from string.h library to compare the strings:

```
 #include <string.h>

 ...

 if (strcmp(temp->name, contactName) == 0) {
     ...
 }
```

See more info here https://stackoverflow.com/a/8004250/492620

Comment: Shouldn't it be `== 0`?

Comment: You mean `==` and not `!=`.Right?

Comment: yes. Sorry, hasty typing ...

Comment: Is there any library dependency to using strcpy()?

Comment: You need to use '#inculde <string.h>' header file in your code

Comment: It's working now, Thank you.